# Testing with multiple upstream repositories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a continuous build and test scenario that I'm trying to figure out how to implement in Jenkins, and I am hoping that someone can lead me in the right direction.

I have a project, `foo`, that depends on a couple of other upstream projects, `bar` and `baz`.  All three projects are under continuous development, with API changes, random failures, etc.  We want to use recent versions of the upstream projects, since they often make changes at our behest.

Given that there are specific known revisions of `bar` and `baz` that work with `foo` such that `foo`'s tests pass, I would like the following:

Whenever `bar` or `baz` change, I would like to build them and test `foo` building against them.  If these tests pass, I would like the new version of `bar`/`baz` to be the new "known good" version.

Whenever `foo` changes, I want to compile against the latest versions of `bar` and `baz`.  If tests pass, the latest versions of `bar` and `baz` become the new "known good" versions.  If tests fail, I want to compile against the last "known good" version of `bar`/`baz`.

The idea is to quickly learn when upstream changes cause problems, and to continue to check changes in our project against known-good upstream versions.  When upstream fails against our project due to upstream bugs, we want to continue using the last known good version for testing.  When upstream fails against our project due to API changes or behavioral improvements, we want to update our code to deal with those, and then switch to these new versions for future builds/testing.

I've glanced at Jenkins Pipeline, and it looks at first glance like it might be able to handle something like this, but I really don't want to go down the rabbit hole of learning a new DSL (and Groovy) if this is not a good fit for our problem.

Comment: At the moment you only have 3 classic jobs, with only the up/down stream mechanism ? Would you like a tag like in git or SVN ?

Comment: What build system does your Jenkins use?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel In reality there are four upstream dependencies that change semi-frequently.  Our project depends on all four, and one of these dependencies depends on the other two.  I simplified the question because I believed that I could extrapolate from the small problem to the larger problem.  As for tags, I don't know?  How would that be useful in solving the underlying problem?

Comment: @ChristianH.Kuhn Our build system consists of scripts which run some combination of `cmake`/`configure`, followed by `make`, followed by `make install`.  We can grab the installs as artifacts.  The underlying projects are (mustly) C and C++.

Comment: @md5i Personally, I would create a new parameterized job that tags your build / versions and trigger it only when your build are successful, in a post-build step. Then, the tag itself is up to you. You can keep all your Jenkins build as tags, you could tag the commits that you built, send a mail etc. It's will be abstracted by the job. - **edit** This is not a solution yet, just an idea, I will write a full answer later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is a combination of **two tasks** -- it will be good to clearly separate those:

1. **Integration tests** of the `bar` and `baz` components using the test framework `foo`
2. Updates of the **test framework** `foo`

### Integration Tests

The first point can be implemented quite easily: basically, whenver `bar` or `baz` successfully pass their "component" CI jobs (say, `bar-test` or `baz-test`, respectively), trigger `foo-test`. In `foo-test`, pick up the versions of `bar` and `baz` and test them. If successful, record those version. Recording could be in several ways, e.g.,

- store in build data of `foo` (console output, build artifact)
- create some tag in your SCM system
- use the [promoted builds plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) to mark builds of `bar` and `baz`

### Updating the Test Framework

Point "2." is a bit more difficult in this context, and I think it is unwise to use one and the same `foo-test` job for the purposes of "1." and "2.": the objective here is completely different from integrating `bar` and `baz`, and especially the handling from SCM side is very different. It will be good to create a dedicated job -- say, `foo-update` -- for updating the version of `foo` that must be used for integrating `bar` and `baz`.

Such a job `foo-update` could work as follows:

- Trigger execution whenever `foo` changes
- When running, use the last known good versions of `bar` and `baz`, as determined in task "1."
- Perform `foo` integration tests of `bar` and `baz`. You know that they did pass successfully before, so...

  - If tests do not pass any longer, then it is due to the changes in `foo`. Manual action is then needed to handle this in `foo`, `bar` or `baz`.
  - If tests do pass, the test framework is compatible. Record the new version of `foo` as the version to be used in integration tests "1."

Recording the proper revision of `foo` can be done again on SCM-level or by recording it in Jenkins itself. Of course, your integration tests in `foo-test` need to pick up that version prior to execution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends if you really want to have all the combinations of `bar` and `baz` versions tested. This might be not trivial. If it's not a problem to test just the latest ones, then assuming you create version of you artifacts for `bar` and `baz` as a derivative of last successful build number, those could look like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        success { 
            build(job: 'test-job', wait: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Now the tricky part is the `test-job`, it should be triggered by either `bar` or `baz`, their versions however might not entirely be known if you pass just one of them a parameter. What I would propose instead would be to query the Jenkins API for latest successful build number of `bar` or `baz` jobs and derive the latest artifact version you would like to base your tests on in `test-job`. From your `test-job` in order to obtain the last successful build number you would do

```
curl --user <userName:password> https://<url>/job/<job-Name>/api/json?xpath=/*/lastStableBuild/number
```

Finally after successful test you would be to label both in your artifact solution as latest verified or something like this (this information would have to be stored in some external system).

This brings us to your `foo` job - it doesn't have a single responsibility, which I find confusing. I would rather say that tests of `bar` and `baz` should be a special job (test and label responsibility). Then `foo` should focus on using either latest verified or just latest artifacts for `bar` and `baz`. (which keeps me wondering, how do you manage versions of `bar` and `baz` in your `foo` project's configuration?)

Comment: `foo` could be split into a build job and a test job.  As for labeling, a quick googling seems to imply that that is a function of the pipeline configuration?  So if, say, compiling `foo` against a newest, unlabeled `bar` and an existing labeled `baz` works, and the tests work, we can then label `bar` as a new latest working version?

Comment: Well this pretty much depends how you would like to store this information. If outcome of `bar` and `baz` would be docker images I would put them into repository as their own versions and after successful testing with `latestVerified` tag for both. How do you store the artifacts produced by `bar` and `baz`? How does `foo` resolve their versions?

Answer (score 0):

1. The first thing to do is to change how you consume transitive dependencies. Depending on whether you are using maven or Gradle, there are ways to consume the latest version of a dependency. For example, with Gradle, you could say:

`compile "junit:junit:+"`

I have seen `latest.release` work in Gradle as well. Find the equivalent approach in maven if you use maven.

2. Assuming it is not the wild west and there is someone reviewing pull-requests in git, `bar` and `baz` could be built after code is merged by some code-owner.
3. In response to any merge on `foo`, `bar`, or `baz` you can run a jenkins job that runs a bunch of tests. Use the [pull-request-builder](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin) Jenkins plugin to kick off builds upon merges. This approach does not require you to learn a new DSL or groovy.

Hope this works.